# Jira REST API - Create issue : Get required fields defined in workflow transition validators

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

From my software, I use the REST API of Jira Cloud to create issues.
I want to fill automatically all required fields with any value, without asking the user anything.

If the issue type has *standard* required fields, I am able to retrieve them with `/rest/api/3/issue/createmeta`.

In a Jira workflow, we can define validators on a transition for issue creation.
It is possible to add a validator to require a field to have a value.

So via the REST API, is it possible to retrieve these required fields defined in validators ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to retrieve the validators of workflow transitions with `/rest/api/3/workflow/search?expand=transitions.rules`.

In the response, I can get the required fields with the validator of type `FieldRequiredValidator`

But this requires having administrator rights...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a way to do that. I could imagine getting the workflow XML and parsing it to find the validators on a transition. But how do I know what a custom validator is making required?